# EasyMock: Partially mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Do all the methods that are not mocked on a mocked class work work as normal?

**E.G.**

Given the object

```
public class Shape {
    public void createShape(...){
        ....
    }

    public void removeShape(...){
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

if this was mocked out like

```
shape = createMock(Shape.class, new Method[]{Shape.class.getMethod("removeShape", new Class[]{...})});
```

would all the other methods like `createShape()` work or do  you have to mock out all methods you want to use?

Comment: Why not just try that out?

Comment: I have tried something similar out and it does not look like all the other methods work but as i am only learning the easymock framework im not sure if it is possible to do this another way or if i have done something incorrect in my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes.

Partial Mocks work exactly like an instance of the mocked class, but they have the ability to add expectations for the method you have set as mocked.
This is usually helpful when you've got an overriding method that also relies on the super class implementation of that method.

It looks like your example is using the deprecated createMock(Class, Method...) method, so I'll provide an example of how you should create a partial mock for your Shape class.

```
final IMockBuilder<Shape> mockBuilder = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Shape.class);
mockBuilder.addMockedMethod(Shape.class.getMethod("removeShape", new Class[]{...}));
final Shape mockShape = mockBuilder.createMock();
```

This will provide a Shape object that behaves perfectly normally, until it tries to use the removeShape method, where it will require some expectations for the behaviour.

Personally, I very rarely use the addMockedMethod version that takes a Method parameter. Usually, the method I'm mocking is distinct enough to use the addMockedMethod(String) version. So I would most likely use the following:

```
final IMockBuilder<Shape> mockBuilder = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Shape.class);
mockBuilder.addMockedMethod("removeShape");
final Shape mockShape = mockBuilder.createMock();
```

This is a little cleaner to my eyes and achieves the same results.

Keep in mind though, these partial mocks live by the same laws as full mocks do.
So you can't mock out final methods like this.

Hope that Helps